# Finding duplicates in one column with non-dups in another

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with how to take a dataset and output a result that finds duplicate information in one column with non-duplicate items in another. If say column 0 and 2 are exact duplicates I don't care about the set of data, only if there are rows where column 0 has entries with more than one value in column 2. And, if that is the case, I want all of the rows that match column 0.

I am first using concat to narrow down the dataset to rows that have duplicates. My problem is now trying to get only the rows where column 2 is different.

My example dataset is:

```
Pattern or URI,Route Filter Clause,Partition,Pattern Usage,Owning Object,Owning Object Partition,Cluster ID,Catalog Name,Route String,Device Name,Device Description
"11111",,Prod_P,Device,"11111",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFF0723AFE8,device1
"11111",,Prod_P,Device,"11111",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFF862FAF74,device2
"11111",,Prod_P,Device,"11111",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFF2A8AA38,device3
"11111",,Prod_P,Device,"11111",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFD2C0A2C6,device4
"22334",,Prod_P,Device,"22334",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFCF87AB31,device5
"33333",,Prod_P,Device,"33333",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFCF87AAEA,device6
"33333",,Dummy_P,Device,"33333",Dummy_P,,,,SEPFFFF18FF65A0,device7
"33333",,Prod_P,Device,"33333",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFCFCCAABB,device8
```

In this set, I want to have a result of the last three rows that are "33333" as they have more than one type of value in column 2. "11111" only matches Prod_P so I don't care about it.

```
import pandas as pd
ignorelist = []
inputfile = "pandas-problem-data.txt"
data = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
data = pd.concat(g for _, g in data.groupby("Pattern_or_URI") if len(g) > 1)
data = data.loc[(data["Pattern_Usage"]=="Device"), ["Pattern_or_URI","Partition","Pattern_Usage","Device_Name","Device_Description"]]
new_rows = []
tempdup = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if row["Pattern_or_URI"] in ignorelist:
        continue
    ignorelist.append(row["Pattern_or_URI"])
    # testdup = pd.concat(h for _, h in (data.loc[(data["Pattern_or_URI"]==row["Pattern_or_URI"], ["Pattern_or_URI","Partition","Pattern_Usage","Device_Name","Device_Description"])]).groupby("Partition") if len(h) > 1)
    # print(data.loc[(data["Pattern_or_URI"]==row["Pattern_or_URI"], ["Pattern_or_URI","Partition","Pattern_Usage","Device_Name","Device_Description"])])
    newrow = data.loc[(data["Pattern_or_URI"]==row["Pattern_or_URI"], ["Pattern_or_URI","Partition","Pattern_Usage","Device_Name","Device_Description"])]
```

If I uncomment the line where I try to use the same concat to find entries with "Partition" > 1 I get an error `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`. I know it gets through the first iter with the print statement uncommented.

Is there an easier or better way of doing this? I'm new to pandas and keep thinking there is probably a way to find this that I haven't figured out. 
Thank you.

Desired output:

```
Pattern or URI,Route Filter Clause,Partition,Pattern Usage,Owning Object,Owning Object Partition,Cluster ID,Catalog Name,Route String,Device Name,Device Description
"33333",,Prod_P,Device,"33333",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFCF87AAEA,device6
"33333",,Dummy_P,Device,"33333",Dummy_P,,,,SEPFFFF18FF65A0,device7
"33333",,Prod_P,Device,"33333",Prod_P,,,,SEPFFFFCFCCAABB,device8
```

Comment: Much easier-Use [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), give it the columns you care about, and set `keep=False`

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson, maybe I don't understand how that works. For example, I removed the loop and added `data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Pattern_or_URI","Partition"], keep=False)` and I ended up with the 11111 rows that I don't want.

Comment: Did you assign it to itself or a new df, or did you pass `inplace=True`? See my answer

Comment: @user3483203 may have a better answer depending on what your actual problem case is. Mine is only good for actual duplicates, but yours don't necessarily look like strict duplicates. I would make sure you verify your output looks like what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bit misleading to say you're looking for duplicates.  This is really a grouping problem.

You want to find groups of identical values in `Pattern or URI` that correspond with more than one unique value in your `Partition` Series.

---

#### `transform` + `nunique`

```
s = df.groupby('Pattern or URI')['Partition'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
df.loc[s]
```

```
   Pattern or URI  Route Filter Clause Partition Pattern Usage  Owning Object Owning Object Partition  Cluster ID  Catalog Name  Route String      Device Name Device Description
5           33333                  NaN    Prod_P        Device          33333                  Prod_P         NaN           NaN           NaN  SEPFFFFCF87AAEA            device6
6           33333                  NaN   Dummy_P        Device          33333                 Dummy_P         NaN           NaN           NaN  SEPFFFF18FF65A0            device7
7           33333                  NaN    Prod_P        Device          33333                  Prod_P         NaN           NaN           NaN  SEPFFFFCFCCAABB            device8
```

Comment: This answer provided the result I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Using `df.drop_duplicates()` as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[111,111,111,222,222,333,333,333], 
                 'b':['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','c'],
                 'c':[12,13,14,15,61,71,81,19]})
df

    a   b   c
0   111 a   12
1   111 a   13
2   111 a   14
3   222 b   15
4   222 b   61
5   333 a   71
6   333 b   81
7   333 c   19

df1=df.drop_duplicates(['a','b'],keep=False)

df1

    a   b   c
5   333 a   71
6   333 b   81
7   333 c   19
```

Note, instead of assigning it to a new DF, you can add `inplace=True` to apply it to the original

Comment: I had just been printing the data.drop_duplicates. Your solution works. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeGross it is impossible to get your desired result using `drop_duplicates`

Comment: When I removed the loop and added `df1 = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Pattern_or_URI","Partition"], keep=False)
print(df1)` I got a result showing only the 33333. I will do more testing with a larger set of data. I will also try the way you posted. Thank you.

Comment: No, you are right. It appears as though my original set I tested on wasn't exactly what I posted here so it only looked right when I first ran it.